# Extract chars from array as UINT32

Tags: c, arrays, data-conversion

So I have a buffer filled with bytes that I know should be at least 16 bytes long.
I dont care about bytes 0 - 11.
I know that the 4 bytes from 12 to 15 represent a 32 bit number.

How can I just extract these bytes and represent them as a 32 bit number.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert each byte to an 8-bit unsigned number, and you can combine these numbers to one 32-bit number using bit operations:

```
uint32_t result = 0;

for (int i = 12; i < 16; i++) {
    result <<= 8;
    result |= (uint8_t)bytes[i];
}
```

Comment: I know the the value should be 191. But this method gives me 808469062

Comment: @dubbeat perhaps an endianness issue? (i. e. you should start at the other end of the byte quartet.) (btw, 191 fits into one `unsigned char` perfectly well – do you really need 4 bytes for this? And did you examine the actual contents of your buffer, e. g. using a debugger or by printing it byte-by-byte?)

Answer (score 0):

I have a fixation with `unions{}`, I can't help it. This might help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

uint32_t
convert_int(char bytes[4])
{
        union {uint32_t n; char bytes[4];} box;

        memcpy(&box.bytes[0], bytes, sizeof(*bytes));
        return ntohl(box.n);
}

int
main(void)
{

        uint32_t number;

        number = convert_int("\x0A\x00\x00\x00");
        printf("%d\n", number);
        return 0;
}
```

`convert_int()` accepts 4 bytes in network byte order (Big endian) (most significant byte first) and translate it to a 32 bits integer; host byte order (either Big or little endian). Since you have control over the buffer, you can place the argument as needed.